# Inconsistent returning of data in crystal report 2013

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

I have a huge data that should be printed in the crystal report. I have a datefrom and dateto parameter to load the data in that certain date. However, not all the data are displayed in the crystal report like what is in the database. Our query is returning correctly in the database but in the crystal report, the data are inconsistent.

Comment: do you mean data is missing? can you check how many records are buffered in crystal reports?

Comment: yes. other data are missing but when I restart the crystal report, it displays.